# Gitlab does not generate emails

Tags: email, gitlab

I have just updated our Gitlab instance and wanted to finally configure everything so that notification mails can get sent out. Unfortunately, Gitlab seems to not even generate any notification mails.

Gitlab version is 7.5, installed and updated according to the manual installation guide.

I have `email_enabled: true` and `email_from: real.address@example.com` in `config/gitlab.yml`. As we do not run a full mail server on that machine, but instead use sSMTP, I have also adjusted `config/initializers/smtp_settings.rb` for sendmail usage:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  Gitlab::Application.config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail

  ActionMailer::Base.sendmail_settings = {
    location: "/usr/bin/sendmail",
    arguments: "-i -t"
  }
end
```

After a restart of Gitlab I tried to create a new repository (which should produce an email AFAIK), but I can find no mention of any mail generation in the log files (both the Gitlab logs as well as `/var/log/mail.log`) and there are no failed background jobs. It just seems like the mail was never created.

- Have any of you seen a similiar behaviour before?
- Is there a possibility in Gitlab to generate a test mail? (I haven't found one)

Comment: Try setting your rails environment to production with this on the command line before restarting Gitlab: `RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: I tried it using `RAILS_ENV=production /etc/init.d/gitlab restart`. Gitlab shows the same behaviour, no mention of mails in the log files. I am pretty sure it actually runs in production mode, as it writes in the `production.log` file.

Comment: Ah, okay ...I have little experience with rails so I saw the `if Rails.env.production` piece and wanted to make sure :)